# aws sts assume role returns accesskeyid masked "***"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, assume-role

I am invoking `sts assume role` inside a codebuild image and the response credential has `accessKeyId = "***"` like this.

Also when tried the same command from my local machine got a proper accesskeyId. Any idea on what I am missing here ?

Request:

`aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::11111111:role/codepipeline_role --role-session-name codepipeline_role`

Sample response:

`{
  "AssumedRoleUser": {
    "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::111111111111:assumed-role/codepipeline_role/codepipeline-role",
    "AssumedRoleId": "AROA6DS4I2EQXD2H5OXYE:codepipeline-role"
  },
  "Credentials": {
    "AccessKeyId": "***",
    "Expiration": "2020-01-04T16:23:56Z",
    "SecretAccessKey": "SecretAccessKey",
    "SessionToken": "sessionTOken"
  }
}`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Very strange that some process would mask the access key but not the secret key. If anything, that's backwards but a normal STS AssumeRole would not mask either in its response (otherwise you obviously could not make use of the returned credentials). How are you actually invoking sts assume role? Is there any code that could be doing this masking?

Comment: @jarmod yes, pretty strange indeed. here is the how i invoke the sts, i have update the question with the request I make using sts. To give a bit of context; I am trying to do a cross account deploy of a serverless app using codebuild.

Comment: CodePipeline has a feature that masks secrets in awscli output (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/reference-pipeline-structure.html). Not 100% sure this is your issue but worth reading.

Comment: The "***" is the result of best-effort masking of sensitive information from the log file done by CodeBuild. You need both the access key and the secret to use the creds, so masking either or both works. However, only the access key id has specific prefix “AKIA” and “ASIA” with a length of 20 chars. Secret access key is 40 random characters, attempting to mask that could mask any non-secret access key string that happens to be 40 chars long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you just try to use the values? It could be masked while echoing.

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - apt-get update
      - apt-get install -y jq
      - RESPONSE=$(aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/CLIRole --role-session-name `date "+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S"`)
      - export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$(echo $RESPONSE | jq -r '.Credentials.AccessKeyId')
      - export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$(echo $RESPONSE | jq -r '.Credentials.SecretAccessKey')
      - export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=$(echo $RESPONSE | jq -r '.Credentials.SessionToken')
      #- Your aws cli command here...
```

### Edit 1:

Checked using following buildspec (CodeBuild invoked from CodePipeline) and can confirm the role assumption was successful. The "***" is masking just when you are echoing:

```
version: 0.2 

phases: 
  install: 
    runtime-versions: 
      nodejs: 8 
    commands: 
      - ASSUME_ROLE_ARN="arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/Shariq-Assumption-Test-Role" 
      - aws sts get-caller-identity 
      - TEMP_ROLE=`aws sts assume-role --role-arn $ASSUME_ROLE_ARN --role-session-name test` 
      - export TEMP_ROLE 
      - echo $TEMP_ROLE 
      - export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$(echo "${TEMP_ROLE}" | jq -r '.Credentials.AccessKeyId') 
      - export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$(echo "${TEMP_ROLE}" | jq -r '.Credentials.SecretAccessKey') 
      - export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=$(echo "${TEMP_ROLE}" | jq -r '.Credentials.SessionToken') 
      - echo $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID 
      - echo $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY 
      - echo $AWS_SESSION_TOKEN 
      - aws sts get-caller-identity
```

'Shariq-Assumption-Test-Role' had following Trust Policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::12345678910:root",
        "Service": "codebuild.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Also, CodeBuild role should have sts:AssumeRole permission.

Build Logs:

```
[Container] 2020/01/05 12:59:13 Running command ASSUME_ROLE_ARN="arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/Shariq-Assumption-Test-Role" 

[Container] 2020/01/05 12:59:13 Running command aws sts get-caller-identity 
{ 
    "UserId": "AROAXTEXAMPLEQ22FQDC:AWSCodeBuild-xxxxxxxx-104c-42b9-b71c-ff3e8ad44b16", 
    "Account": "123456789012", 
    "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::123456789012:assumed-role/codebuild-build-from-cp-service-role/AWSCodeBuild-xxxxxxxx-104c-42b9-b71c-ff3e8ad44b16" 
} 

[Container] 2020/01/05 12:59:18 Running command TEMP_ROLE=`aws sts assume-role --role-arn $ASSUME_ROLE_ARN --role-session-name test` 

[Container] 2020/01/05 12:59:18 Running command export TEMP_ROLE 

[Container] 2020/01/05 12:59:18 Running command echo $TEMP_ROLE 
{ "Credentials": { "AccessKeyId": "***", "SecretAccessKey": "R9QuqToY4qkcEXAMPLESGmTGJi4QawzS", "SessionToken": "FwoGZXIvYXdzEA4aDIwhkn5nVvvFBeBxXSLGAZmE1/Kw0CA9a/PEUG6VXyHyTrVryYzyRDEPdFUlzhXjqBj9h5x/Cz5aX/61aR2qSEXAMPLEBqm7OsI3zD3KA3NIIAr/u+l9f8AGZz+Ii6AeUoLFrkvH7d7JINGvouRNdrulkbzbnAAtGQx+8K1DxR0w4TbPbld3hQJYanGf6I4v3EieJuRckqxloEO6gF9W9EsqsluOogJVJAziimu8fwBTJLaKyaqg2Rr6w4JqrIB9fUngEnif/ggbIrscuadGLhXe7bSRKCrerk5DzEGP1uiZwH3P/De9wIOOClq", "Expiration": "2020-01-05T13:59:18Z" }, "AssumedRoleUser": { "AssumedRoleId": "AROAXTLSHEXAMPLE2TZT:test", "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::123456789012:assumed-role/Shariq-Assumption-Test-Role/test" } } 

[Container] 2020/01/05 12:59:18 Running command export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$(echo "${TEMP_ROLE}" | jq -r '.Credentials.AccessKeyId') 

[Container] 2020/01/05 12:59:18 Running command export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$(echo "${TEMP_ROLE}" | jq -r '.Credentials.SecretAccessKey') 

[Container] 2020/01/05 12:59:18 Running command export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=$(echo "${TEMP_ROLE}" | jq -r '.Credentials.SessionToken') 

[Container] 2020/01/05 12:59:18 Running command echo $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID 
*** 

[Container] 2020/01/05 12:59:18 Running command echo $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY 
R9QuqToY4qkct327ZEXAMPLEmTGJi4QawzS 

[Container] 2020/01/05 12:59:18 Running command echo $AWS_SESSION_TOKEN 
FwoGZXIvYXdzEA4aDIwhkn5nVvvFBeBxXSLGAZmE1/Kw0CA9a/PEUG6VXyHyTrVryYzyRDEPdFUlzhXjqBj9h5x/Cz5aX/61aR2qSGwqMEjJToh0Bqm7OsI3zD3K4ot7wAeUoLFrkvH7d7JINGvouRNdrulkbzbnAAtGQx+8K1DxR0w4TbPbld3hQJYanEXAMPLE0h3U5xLXykuEcvOnuV6gF9W9EsqsluOogJVJAziimu8fwBTJLaKyaqg2Rr6w4JqrIB9fUngEnif/ggbIrscuadGLhXe7bSRKCrerk5DzEGPzqyMFCH+DHYsbeIeqXkbFYW1uiZwH3P/De9wIOOClq 

[Container] 2020/01/05 12:59:18 Running command aws sts get-caller-identity 
{ 
    "UserId": "AROAXTLEXAMPLELVE2TZT:test", 
    "Account": "123456789012", 
    "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::123456789012:assumed-role/Shariq-Assumption-Test-Role/test" 
}
```

Comment: yes, I have tried the approach before too and it had no effect.

Comment: Please see Edit 1.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and the sample. you are right its only masked on an echo.

Comment: Thanks for explaining with the sample on how to use assume role